# Mercurial repository corruption repair says it's not a mercurial repository?

Tags: mercurial, tortoisehg, bitbucket

So I have managed to corrupt my mercurial repo. So I am following the steps from the [repository corruption](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/RepositoryCorruption) page on the wiki to repair it.

When I run the convert command:

> hg convert --config convert.hg.ignoreerrors=True REPO REPOFIX

It gives me the following output:

```
initializing destination REPOFIX repository  
REPO does not look like a CVS checkout  
REPO does not look like a Git repository  
REPO does not look like a Subversion repository  
REPO is not a local Mercurial repository  
REPO does not look like a darcs repository  
REPO does not look like a monotone repository  
REPO does not look like a GNU Arch repository  
REPO does not look like a Bazaar repository  
cannot find required "p4" tool
```

Why on earth would it say that? And how can I go about fixing it?

It definitely is a mercurial repository, it's hosted on Bitbucket, and I am using Tortoisehg to manage it.

Edit:

I think maybe I can't do this against a remote repository? How can I go about fixing this then?

Answer (score 0):

You probably did not corrupt the remote repository at Bitbucket, did you?

It's more likely you corrupted your local copy, and so you can just clone it from Bitbucket again or try the `hg convert …` trick on your local copy (i.e. the folder you manage with TortoiseHG).

Comment: hi thanks, I tried hg convert, but it said that my repository wasn't a mercurial repo? (which it is?) thx

Comment: did you use the ROOT of the Repo (the directory containing the (hidden) directory '.hg') ?

Comment: i think so its the only directory i have

Answer (score 0):

A bit late but I faced the same issue. The mistake was running that command inside the project folder. You have to run the command outside the folder containing the .hg file. I could not find a way through TortoiseHg console to move up a directory so I used windows terminal.